# Bash adding \r to every string

Tags: bash, shell-script, newlines

I am trying to create a simple Linux BASH script but notice that bash is adding \r to every string, and if I try to remove it with 'tr' then it just add a new one!  Here's my script

```
#!/bin/bash
OUTFILE=$(echo -n `date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H-%m-%S"`)
ASD='DDD'
echo -n "DATE [$OUTFILE]"
echo -n "DDD [$ASD]"
```

and here is the output

```
 bash -x backup-datadir.sh
+++ date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%m-%S
++ echo -n 2020-03-09_13-03-44
+ OUTFILE=$'2020-03-09_13-03-44\r'
+ ASD=$'DDD\r'
' echo -n 'DATE [2020-03-09_13-03-44
' echo -n 'DDD [DDD-03-44
```

Why is that extra \r appearing?  The ] is gone because it is overwritten after the newline.  I've never seen this before...

Comment: What operating system are you using? Is this on Windows by any chance? Or did you create the script on Windows?

Comment: There is a CR in your script after the last ) on the OUTFILE assignment, and another at the end of the ASD assignment. Print the script with `cat -vet` to see these.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant, at the end of each and every line. The result looks a bit weirder than usual because there's two `CR`'s in each `echo`, and no actual newlines.

Comment: @ilkkachu. I have seen posts here for `/bin/bash: not found` caused by \r on the shebang. So I was fairly sure that the shebang was edited in separately. But no: it is being explicitly run by a bash command, so the shebang is just a comment, so a \r makes no difference. And why use a .sh extension? Windows continues its malign influence in so many ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your script is a DOS text file, meaning it contains a carriage return character (often written `\r`) at the end of each and every line.  Unix text files don't have this, and when a Unix system is outputting such a character, it causes the cursor position to move to the very start of the line. Further output to that line will then overwrite what was previously outputted there.

Converting the script to a Unix text file will solve your issue:

```
$ bash -x script.sh
+++ date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%m-%S
++ echo -n 2020-03-09_21-03-47
+ OUTFILE=$'2020-03-09_21-03-47\r'
+ ASD=$'DDD\r'
' echo -n 'DATE [2020-03-09_21-03-47
' echo -n 'DDD [DDD-03-47
```

```
$ dos2unix script.sh
dos2unix: converting file script.sh to Unix format...
```

```
$ bash -x script.sh
+++ date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%m-%S
++ echo -n 2020-03-09_21-03-03
+ OUTFILE=2020-03-09_21-03-03
+ ASD=DDD
+ echo -n 'DATE [2020-03-09_21-03-03]'
DATE [2020-03-09_21-03-03]+ echo -n 'DDD [DDD]'
DDD [DDD]
```

(there is no newline after output on the last line due to using `echo -n`).

```
$ bash script.sh
DATE [2020-03-09_21-03-19]DDD [DDD]
```

(there is no newline after output on the last line due to using `echo -n`).

Comment: I had cut and paste from a web page directly into a linux editor, so I assumed the \r wouldn't paste in.  But I was wrong...

Comment: A Web page rendered on a Windows machine?